# return yes or no based on cell data from another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, if

I have two sheets.
The first sheet "Example A" and the second sheet "Example B".
Example A has a master sheet of clients that may also be on Example B. If the client is listed on Example B, Example A, should return the word "Yes", if it is not on Example B, it should return "No".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use MATCH() which will return a number if found and an error if not.

Using ISNUMBER() we can get a TRUE/FALSE

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,'Example B'!A:A,0)),"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

**=IF(COUNTIF(B!$A$1:$A$5,A!A1)>=1,"Yes","No")**

*Table A:*

[image]

*Table B:*

[image]

If your table is different, please provide the sample about your problem.